# how to enable (https) SSL certificate AWS EC2 hosted site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

So far i did below configuration.

1. I hosted my site on EC2 AWS machine. Public ip and public DNS.
2. I can access my website by ip as well as public DNS.
3. I purchased domain name from GoDaddy. www.xxtrasc.com
4. On AWS I created Hosted Zone then map www.app.xxtrasc.com successfully.

Now i access my website directly www.app.xxtrasc.com

Next want to enable https

1. On AWS Certificate Manager order certificate with domain name *.xxtrasc.com
   Did everything to add CNAME and all. I can see status gree colored Issued on ACM.

Now how i can attached this certificate to my web site so that i can access https://www.app.xxtrasc.com

Comment: Usually you would use ssl certs on CloudFront or ELB which are placed in front of your EC2 instance. If you want to host it directly on EC2 instance, then I think `nginx` would be easiest to setup for that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ACM to directly install your ACM Certificate on your AWS based website or application
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-install.html
You must use one of the following services:

1. Elastic Load Balancing
2. Amazon CloudFront
3. AWS Elastic Beanstalk
4. Amazon API Gateway
5. AWS CloudFormation
   Please read the official doc : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html
   So to install the certificate directly under apache2/nginx configuration you need to obtain the certificate from other third parties like Lets Encrypt, GoDaddy etc. you can read about that here - https://in.godaddy.com/help/manually-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-apache-server-centos-5238

On AWS I recommend using an ELB an placing your EC2 instances behind this ELB. This will allow you to select your ACM certificate from ELB itslef. Please read following doc to use classic load balancer with HTTPS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ssl-server-cert.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable SSL on your site, you need to purchase SSL certificate. You can purchase it with Godaddy and then setup it on AWS server. Without SSL certificate, your https site won't work.